# Using Redis as the primary Rails store

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nosql, redis

How can I use Redis as the primary data store for a Rails app, and omit the SQL db? Is there an ORM / adapter that can translate Rails models into Redis objects in the same seamless manner as the SQL adapters / ActiveRecord ?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to find a one-to-one Redis Active-Record replacement for RDBs yet.  Instead your best bet is to use the [redis-rb gem](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb).

This provides a solid interface that maps very directly to the actual redis commands that exist on [their website](http://redis.io/commands).  Though you lose out on a lot of callbacks built in to rails, with a bit of legwork you can create an similar custom framework yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [LINK](http://jimneath.org/2011/03/24/using-redis-with-ruby-on-rails.html#redis_and_rails) out.  Navigate down to the example uses in rails.  They talk about ActiveRecord and Rails....not a rails dev so not sure if this actually maps into ActiveRecord the same way it does for you with an RDBMS.

--S

Comment: I actually found this article last night. Since redis is an in memory data store, rails just provides a $redis object that you can write to. So in a way have to write your own adapter. It would be nice if someone wrote a nicely designed ruby framework for systematically storing ruby objects in redis. Something I might work on.